# How to define a cyclic type definition?

Tags: scala

This is not a valid type definition:

```
scala>  type Addable = { def +(subject: Addable) }
<console>:4: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type Addable
        type Addable = { def +(subject: Addable) }
```

Can this be expressed in scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't.

On page 40 of The Scala Language Specification Version 2.7:

> However, it is a static error if a
>   type alias refers recursively to the
>   defined type constructor itself.  That
>   is, the type *T* in a type alias
>   ***type*** t[tps] = T may not refer directly or indirectly to the name
>   *t*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in a library I wrote, HTH:

```
  trait Addable {
    type AddableType <: Addable
    def + (subject: AddableType): AddableType
  }
  trait Rational extends Addable {
    type AddableType = Rational
    override def + (subject: Rational): Rational 
  }
```

Comment: The definition has to be a structural type as the underlining classes cannot be changed (like Int, Long).

Comment: Hm, perhaps you could define a view (implicit def) to convert these classes to Addable?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this may be "fixed" in Scala 2.8:

http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1291

Comment: It does not work with the current nightly build.

Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r18457-b20090810020144 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client V
M, Java 1.6.0_12).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class A{
     |     type Addable = { def +(subject: Addable) }
     | }
<console>:5: error: illegal cyclic reference involving method +
           type Addable = { def +(subject: Addable) }

At least the error message changed :-).

Comment: Did you try the experimental command line option mentioned at the bottom of the above article?

Comment: Same result with: scala -Yrecursion  10